# Is a set containing only one reflexive ordered pair transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not too sure how I can go into much detail.
However, if we consider the set { < a , a > }. Does it hold that this set obeys transitivity?

And if so, does it do it vacuously, or non-vacuously?

Thank you in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It obeys transitivity non-vacuously. For the definition says:

> For all $x, y, z$:
>    $\langle x, y\rangle, \langle y, z \rangle \in R \implies \langle x, z \rangle \in R$

In this case, it is true for the only occurrence of the above happens for $x = y = z = a$ for which you do have that $\langle x, z \rangle = \langle a, a \rangle \in R$.

---

It would've been vacuously true in a case like $\{\langle1, 2\rangle\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It makes sense to me now!